# using a url variable in a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I got a variable out of the url in my wordpress template

```
$ref = urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['ref']);
```

Then I have a function (in function.php) that check to a corresponding email address

```
function lookup_email_adres($ref){
   switch ($ref) {
      case "example1":
         return "example1@example.com";
         break;
      case "example2":
         return "example2@example.com";
         break;
      default:
      return "example3@example.com";
}
```

This all works fine.
But now I have a plugin that makes a form, and I want this plugin to sent it to the email address corresponding to the `$ref` from the url.

In the plugin it sents to the variable `$recipient`. If I type `$recipient = 'example@example.com'` it works. But if I create `$recipient = lookup_email_adres($ref);` It won't.

If I use `$ref = 'example'`, before `$recipient = lookup_email_adres($ref);` it works too.

I just can't get the plugin to use the `$ref` from the url.

How can I use this `$ref` from the url in my plugin.

Comment: paste here content of function `lookup_email_adres()`. It is not standard wp function.

Comment: added the function

Comment: your code looks good (except you've missed one `}` in function block). Is `$wp_query` globalized? what if you use `$_GET['ref']` instead?